# Dynamically creating .class file

Tags: java, bytecode

I have defined a grammar through which I produce a series of abstract syntax trees of sorts. For example

```
x = 7
println + * x 2 5
```

becomes

```
    (assign)
    /      \
   x        7

    (println)
        |
       (+)
      /   \
    (*)    5
   /   \
  x     2
```

These trees are made from various `Node` classes representing values and operations. Now, these trees are easy to *interpret* but my goal is to generate Java bytecode representing these processes. My question is, what would be the best way to approach that? Should I just literally write various [bytecode instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) to a .class file, or is there some library or interface that can help with this sort of thing?

Comment: http://www.antlr.org/ ? Also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380498/create-a-jvm-programming-language

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum As far as I know ANTLR helps with the parsing process, but I already have that taken care of. I just want to write the Java bytecode dynamically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Bytecode Manipulation Library Suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532215/java-bytecode-manipulation-library-suggestions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. ASM and BCEL are two Java libraries designed to assist with runtime generation of classfiles.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a framework that lets you compose code with declarative expression trees and then compile them to bytecode.  Though I had developed it to ease runtime code generation, it could just as easily be leveraged as a sort of compiler back end, e.g., by translating your syntax tree into one of my expression trees.

At the very least, you could probably glean some useful bits from my compiler and maybe use my low-level code generation framework.

My repository is [here](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/).  The expression tree library is `procyon-expressions`.

Comment: Do you use another library such as ASM within your framework?

Comment: No, I have my own TypeBuilder and CodeGenerator.  I have no third party dependencies for this particular framework.  I find ASM extremely cumbersome to use.